# Unable to access variable in Meteor event

Tags: javascript, meteor

When I fire a click event, this function runs:

```
'click h2.start1': function () {
      var genreName;
      //generate random number
      function getGenreNumber () {
        numGenre = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500) + 1); //total genres: 1381
        console.log('genre index number: ' + numGenre);
        return numGenre
      };
      //http.get genre with number genre/list
      function getGenreName () {
        HTTP.get('someurl',
        {},
        function (error, result) {
          if (result.statusCode === 200) {
            genreName = result.data.response.genres[numGenre].name;
            console.log('The genre is: ' + genreName);
          }
        return genreName
        });
      };
      //http.get 15 artists of genre genre/artist
      function getGenreArtists () {
        console.log('genreName is: ' + genreName); //this is undefined
        HTTP.get('someurl' + genreName,
        {},
        function (error, result) {
          if (result.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log(result.data.response);
            console.log(genreName);
          }else {
            console.log("something broke");
            console.log(genreName); //this is exactly as it should be!
          }
        });
      };
      getGenreNumber()
      getGenreName()
      getGenreArtists()
},
```

I'm trying to do two things, first, to have the value of variable `genreName` passed into the url of the GET request in the function `getGenreArtists`.

The first console.log in `getGenreArtists` comes back undefined, but the console.log under the line "something broke" returns correctly.

I'm confused because both functions have the same scope, and because the function `getGenreName` is able to access the variable `numGenre` correctly.

The second thing I'm trying to do is replace any spaces with a `+` in `genreName` so the url of the GET request will be formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an ordinary Asynchronous problem. Generally speaking, if you want to do something with data from an asynchronous event, you pass a callback (or use a promise). As an example, your `getGenreName` would look more like this:

```
function getGenreName(callback) {
  HTTP.get('someurl', {}. function (error, result) {
    if (result.statusCode === 200) {
      callback(result.data.response.genres[numGenre].name);
    }
  });
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
getGenreName(function (name) {
  console.log('the name of the genre is: ' + name);
});
```

Comment: Agreed - the variable genreName is set by the callback in getGenreName() after trying to read it the first time (line 2 of getGenreArtists func), but before  the callback in getGenreArtists is called.

Comment: Why wouldn't I use a return statement instead of console.log in order to pass the string into the url?

Comment: Because that would cause blocking until the HTTP request finished. With callback methods, you are basically making it do an action when it arrives at its result, but return control immediately. It's much more common to do this in javascript.

Comment: I added the callback, but I'm still confused on how to get the value of `genreName` into the get request for `getGenreArtists`

Comment: It worked by putting the entire rest of `getGenreArtists` within the `getGenreName` callback. Super hacky, but I can refactor later. Thanks!